# What is norm of matrix element in Fermi Golden Rule

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, linear-algebra, matrix-elements, fermis-golden-rule

Fermi Golden Rule says:

$\Gamma \propto |M_{ij}|^2$

I know how to get $M_{ij}$, but how do I proceed? How do I take a norm of Hermitian matrix? There is no clear (to me) definition in the internet except the Frobenius norm, and I don't think that this is it.

I have assumed all my life that

$|M_{ij}|^2 = M_{ij}^{\dagger}M_{ij}$

but since I have got a complex number where I have not expected it, I am not sure any more.

Comment: If you got a complex number there, then you likely made a mistake in your calculation.

Answer (score 1):

The notation just means the magnitude of the complex number $M_{ij}$ for $i$  and $j$ labelling the initial and final states. 
$$
|M_{ij}|^2= |\langle i \vert M\vert j \rangle|^2.
$$
It's not intended to be any of the matrix norms of the operator $M$.

Comment: $M_{ij}$ is a complex matrix (!), not a complex number; it's not an expectation value, it is transition MATRIX. If I proceed, I get $\langle j|\hat{M}^{\dagger}|i\rangle \langle i|\hat{M} |j\rangle = \langle j|\hat{M}^{\dagger}\hat{M}|j\rangle$, and from here I am stuck. Also, is it $|M_{ij}|^2 = \langle j|\hat{M}^{\dagger}|i\rangle \langle i|\hat{M} |j\rangle$ or $|\langle j|\hat{M}^{\dagger}|i\rangle \langle i|\hat{M} |j\rangle|$? Not clear...

Comment: I have never really thought about that, but def of norm of a vector in Hilbert space does not translate into norm of a matrix automatically, so construction $|M_{ij}|^2$ is not that obvious, apparently...

Comment: @MsTais I always thought it was a matrix element. There is but one $i$, the initial state. The final state is usually a plane wave with some density of states in phase space--so you only calculate the magnitude of the matrix element from the initial state to the final state.

Comment: Uf, yes, in ideal world you are given initial and final states and you can collapse everything to numbers... In general it is a matrix, a mapping, you supply $|i\rangle$ and $|f\rangle$ of the system and get the probability of this transition to happen. I can't let it collapse to a number. I need to keep its general form.